# Data not being sent to Servlet from Android via POST

Tags: android, servlets, post

I have an android application from where I need to send an image file to the servlet using POST multipart/form-data. The issue is that the servlet is being called and the response is being received on android phone. But no data is getting received on the server side. Not only the image, but other data such as 'Title' and 'Description' as well.

Can someone please tell me where the issue is?

Android code:

```
public String Sending(){
        String iFileName = "card.png";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String Tag="fSnd";
        String s = null;
        try
        {

                HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload("http://192.168.2.48:8080/ImagePreprocessing/PreprocessingPath", "image","Image to be preprocessed");
                Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);

                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(Title);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(Description);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // close streams
                fileInputStream.close();

                dos.flush();

                Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                // retrieve the response from server
                int ch;

                StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();

                while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ) { 
                    b.append( (char)ch ); 
                }

                s=b.toString();
                Log.i("Response",s);
                dos.close();

        }

        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
                Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
                Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        return s;
}
```

Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet("/PreprocessingPath")
public class Preprocessing extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Preprocessing() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

   /**
 * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String method = request.getMethod();

       doPost(request, response);
}


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Hi from Post");

    // get current date time with Date()
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");                
    Date date = new Date();
    String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);

    // set the filename
    String filename = "IMAGE_" + timestamp +".png";

    String title = request.getParameter("title");

    String description = request.getParameter("description");

    System.out.println("Title: "+ title);
    System.out.println("Description: "+ description);

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("Server says hello !");  

    byte[] byteArray = request.getParameter("filename").getBytes();

    // save the image file on the server
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/NAPSTER/ADT/ImagePreprocessing/WebContent/WEB-INF/"+filename);
    try {
        fos.write(byteArray);
    }
    finally {
        fos.close();
    }

    PreProcessingTest.startPreprocessing(filename);
}
```

}

Console:

```
Hi from Post
Title: null
Description: null
Nov 14, 2014 1:06:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.patternrecognition.preprocessing.Preprocessing] in context with path     [/ImagePreprocessing] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.patternrecognition.preprocessing.Preprocessing.doPost(Preprocessing.java:84)
at com.patternrecognition.preprocessing.Preprocessing.service(Preprocessing.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Logcat:

[image]

Comment: I hope you are not making request on Main thread?

Comment: Yes it is in the main thread. I am doing all this in the Activity class. Not creating any separate thread. Is it an issue?

Comment: Yes, make request to the servelet using asynctask.

Comment: But that is just to do the work in the background. If the servlet is receiving the request, how does it matter if I do it in the main thread or a different thread?

Comment: You might be getting error while making request to servlet?

Comment: No. I have pasted the console output above. It going in the doPost() method very well but gives error when I am trying to do "byte[] byteArray = request.getParameter("filename").getBytes()". Because I am doing getBytes on null.

Comment: Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);, Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);--- check what are they printing.

Comment: Added Logcat image. But I guess that it is coming from the Servlet itself after the client received status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Create a method to create request to the servlet.

```
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {

    if (mHttpClient == null) {

        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}
    public static String postUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
        throws Exception {

    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpost);

        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        is = resEntity.getContent();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),
                1024 * 4);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.wtf("Exception", "Exception: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        in.close();

    }

    return result;

}
```

STEP 2: What ever you want to send add it in List and pass this in asynctask constructor

```
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", "VALUE")));
SendData mSendData = new SendData(URL,
                postParams);
        mSendData .execute();
```

STEP 3: CREATE an asynctask to send the data

```
public class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


String mUrl;
List<NameValuePair> postParams;

public SendLatLong(String URL, List<NameValuePair> postParams) {
    this.mUrl = URL;
    this.postParams = postParams;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        //call that method (postURL) and pass the url of the servlet and namevaluepair
        postUrl(mUrl, postParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Feel free to revert for any query.

Comment: Well I tried doing that. Although it is throwing an exception while receiving the response, but it is too slow. It is taking too much time to process the request itself. Thanks for sharing this method though. Can't we figure out the small issue in my method. it just the data that is not being sent to the server.